# Issue with VF Custom Button in Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I am trying to recreate the 'Close Case' Button in Lightning since SF does not have this as of now. I created a flow and referenced it in the VF code below and set the finishLocation to the original record that the button was clicked.  The issue is that when the button is clicked it opens a new tab in Classic UI displaying the case as I want the button to return to the original record that the button was clicked.  Is there an alternative for this?

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="flowDynamicRedirect">>

    <flow:interview name="Close_Case" finishLocation="{!URLFOR('/' + Case.Id)}">
        <apex:param name="vRecordId" value="{!Case.Id}"/>
    </flow:interview>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a point and click option as a for Close case option in Lightning.

> To give your agents the Close Case action in Lightning Experience,
>   create an action and add it to the case page layout.

The Close Case button is included with Salesforce Classic. However, you must create it in Lightning Experience.

From Setup, click the Object Manager tab. Select Cases, and open the Buttons, Links, and Actions setup page.

1. Click New Action.
2. For Action Type, select Update a Record.
3. For Standard Label Type, select None. For Label, enter Close Case.
   The Name field is auto-filled. Optionally, enter a description and success message.
4. Click Save.
5. To customize the action layout to display only the Status and
   Internal Comments fields, remove the other fields, and click Save.
6. In the Predefined Field Values section, click New.
7. Assign the Status field the Closed field value, and click Save.
8. Go to the Case Page Layouts setup page, and edit your case layout.
9. Drag the new quick action to the Salesforce Mobile and Lightning
   Experience Actions section, and click Save.

> When an agent clicks the action from the Service Console, the Status
>   field displays Closed. Agents can now close a case with two clicks—one
>   for the action button and one to save.

Reference:- [Create a Close Case Quick Action](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cases_set_up_lex_close_case.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks Sanket. Looked into that but want to essentially reduce the number of clicks and with this Close Case Button,  all people will need to do is click 1 button.